# Use case of DB design

Tags: database, database-design

I wondered if there is any site out there with some detailed examples of normalization and DB design in general. Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Why negative?It is just a question, not a wrong answer.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but it is a pretty broad question with a high probability of having already being asked on SO. Not to mention that it is not directly software related. Give http://dba.stackexchange.com/ a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and this [Dev Shed page](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/) should give you a  good start.

The following [blog page](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/09/10-useful-articles-about-database.html) has some links to some good articles on general database design.
The first about the "10 Common Database Design Mistakes" has a good outline of some common pitfalls
and problems seen when database design is not thoroughly planned.

Comment: Thank you...esepacially the blog page will be very useful.